# Filtering Datetime field by date not working in Django

Tags: django, datetime, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to filter a Datetime model field by date only and have tried:

```
Content.objects.filter(created_at__date=params.get("event_date"))
```

The event_date parameter is formed like 2021-04-07. I've tried creating a datetime object and have also tried this:

```
   search_params["created_at__lte"] = datetime.datetime(int(date[0]), int(date[1]), int(date[2]), 0, 0, 0)
    search_params["created_at__gte"] = datetime.datetime(int(date[0]), int(date[1])+1, int(date[2]), 0, 0, 0)
```

However, all of these methods return an empty query set and they should return one result. The result has a Datetime field (2021-04-07 23:00).

EDIT:
My model:

```
class Final_Content(models.Model):
    class Content_Type(models.TextChoices):
        ANIMATION = "ANIMATION", "Animation"
        AUDIO = "AUDIO", "Audio"
        GRAPHIC = "GRAPHIC", "Graphic"
        PHOTO = "PHOTO", "Photo"
        TEXT = "TEXT", "Text"
        VIDEO = "VIDEO", "Video"

    objects: models.Manager
    final_content_id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, verbose_name="Final Media ID"
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Media Title")
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description")
    thumbnail = models.URLField(verbose_name="Thumbnail")
    preview = models.URLField(verbose_name="Preview")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    event_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Event Time")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created At")
```

Comment: So, you need to filter all the objects that have a date-time equivalent to 2021-04-07 23:00??

Comment: please share you content model , especially relationship between 'created_at' and 'date' fields

Comment: In lte-gte code you've mixed up operators: it should be `gte date` and `lte date+1`

Comment: I've added my model. @mike_thecode I need to filter all objects that have a date 2021-04-07, disregarding the time. I've tried all possible combinations and the filter is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

add the following queryset to your viewset:

```
import datetime
queryset = Final_Content.objects.filter(created_at__date=datetime.date(2021, 4, 7))
```

as seen here[QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#date)